# Google-sheet function for cell above in costumized formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a function/formula/script in Google sheets for my own formula.
I have one, where I need the value displayed in the cell above, which I type in manually. The formula is 5.5^(39-XX). So if for example cell B5 has the value 32, in cell B6 I'd like to type something like "=MYFORMULA" into the cell where the calculated value should be displayed. MYFORMULA should be programmed as 5.5^(39-*cellabove*).

I have already tried

```
function MYFORMULA() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var cellRange = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var selectedColumn = cellRange.getColumn();
  var selectedRow = cellRange.getRow();
  Logger.log(`selectedColumn: ${selectedColumn}`);
  Logger.log(`selectedRow: ${selectedRow}`);
  Logger.log(`selected cell vale: ${cellRange.getValue()}`);
  cellRange.setValue('=5.5^(39-(MYFORMULA[-1;]))')
}
```

which does not work, unfortunately. I have the feeling, I have to program a function for the current cell as well. Any suggestions for the code? I am coding into Apps Script in Google tables.
Also, I have to activate a trigger in order to have premission using any newly created function. If you have any suggestions here, too, I would appreciate your help.

Cheers!

Comment: I revised your OP because you refer to Google Docs where as it should be Google Sheets.  Docs is the word processing app.  Some may just ignore your post if they are not familiar with Docs.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than detect the active range and set a value directly, you can implement `MYFORMULA` as a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions), which can take an input that you pass as a cell reference and return a value, which will be written into the cell containing the formula.

### Suggested change

Change your function to include an input variable, and to return a value, without any reference to specific cells, like this:

```
function MYFORMULA(x) { 
    return 5.5**(39-x) 
}
```

(Note `**` is the Javascript symbol for [exponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation))

Then, in your spreadsheet, in cell B6, type `=MYFORMULA(B5)`.  The spreadsheet will pass the value in B5 to your function, and will write the return value in B6.